# Mysql connections in TIME_WAIT state

Tags: mysql, connection, timeout, wait, pooling

I am facing an issue in server wherein couple of connections are being timed out. Below are the errors in the err file:-

```
130401  8:07:06 [Warning] Aborted connection 1111111to db: 'ABC' user: 'u1' host: '1.1.1.1' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
130401  8:10:44 [Warning] Aborted connection 1712056 to db: 'XYZ' user: 'u2' host: '2.2.2.2.' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Below is the config

```
wait_timeout= 900
max_connections                         | 500
max_packet_size                           256M
```

While the historic max connections has not yet reached more than 320, we are seeing that lot of connections are in TIME_WAIT using command:

```
netstat -anlp | grep :3306 | grep TIME_WAIT -wc; date
299
```

On the application side, the client would close the connection if its idle for more than 600secs.

This means that many connections are in wait state. At the same time, the server is not busy. which means that its not in lock state.

Can someone help me on this? Advance thanks.

Sridhar.